# Why is this integration so slow?

Tags: numerical-integration

I am trying to integrate numerically a function. This integral seems quite simple, but it takes forever, and I do not understand why. Here is my code:

```
int1[p2_?NumericQ, p3_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[x2^2 Sin[\[Phi]3] p2 p3, {x2, -1, 1}, {x3, -1, 1}, {\[Phi]2, 0, 2 Pi}, {\[Phi]3, 0, 2 Pi},  Method -> {Automatic, SymbolicProcessing -> 0}];
int2[p2_?NumericQ, s_?NumericQ] :=  NIntegrate[int1[p2, p3], {p3, 0, s}, Method -> {Automatic, SymbolicProcessing -> 0}];
int2[1, 1]
```

How can I speed it up?

Comment: `Integrate[
 x2^2 Sin[\[Phi]3] p2 p3, {x2, -1, 1}, {x3, -1, 1}, {\[Phi]2, 0, 
  2 Pi}, {\[Phi]3, 0, 2 Pi}]` ???

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk I should have explained: this is a MWE for my more complicated real case.

Comment: It's normal behavior. From help pages and possible issues: `Higher-dimensional cubature-based integration to default precision may be slow`.Try:`int3[p2_?NumericQ, s_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  x2^2 Sin[\[Phi]3] p2 p3, {x2, -1, 1}, {x3, -1, 1}, {\[Phi]2, 0, 
   2 Pi}, {\[Phi]3, 0, 2 Pi}, {p3, 0, s}, 
  Method -> "AdaptiveQuasiMonteCarlo", PrecisionGoal -> 2]; int3[1, 1]`.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk: Your code produces "NNIntegrate::maxp: The integral failed to converge after 1000100 integrand evaluations. NIntegrate obtained 0.0014951501785397275` and 0.02563972292353793` for the integral and error estimates."

Comment: @user64494 The integrad is zero, then with: `PrecisionGoal -> 2` the answer is correct.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk: Can you kindly ground your claim " The integrad is zero"? TIA.

Comment: @user64494. `Integrate[
 x2^2 Sin[\[Phi]3] p2 p3 /. p2 -> 1, {x2, -1, 1}, {x3, -1, 
  1}, {\[Phi]2, 0, 2 Pi}, {\[Phi]3, 0, 2 Pi}, {p3, 0, 1}]`=0.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk: Thank you. In this case `NIntegrate` is not needed. Think of the situation when we don't know it.